# Flicker when drawing multiple shapes over image based texture

Tags: directx, directx11, directx9, sharpdx, rendertexture

I'm rendering video frames with multiple color filled shapes over it using SharpDx and D3D11.

Rendering seems to be fine when just rendering the video frame and is as expected.

Now if i draw a single color filled shape it is drawn and rendered as expected.

Hoever, the problem occurs when I'm trying to render more than one color filled shapes over a video frame texture.

Apart from first  colored shape , all other shapes drawn flicker when rendered thus showing the pixels under neath which are the pixels for the rendered video frame.

Any ideas as to why does this occur ?

If any more information is required then do let me know.

P.S. Using ShaprDx and Directx11

Thanks.

**Edit:**
It seemed to be due to rendering the color filled shapes with the same z order as the underlying texture.

This was resolved with recommendation from another forum available [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/679635-flicker-when-rendering-multiple-shapes-over-image-texture/) as long i'm just drawing a shape filled with color but when i'm filling the quad/shapes with textures the problem is still there.

I have also tried to set the ZOrder for the each of the shapes to be different yet the problem is still there.